# Erro ao compilar meu projeto

Tags: android, android-studio

Alguém consegue me ajudar a corrigir esses erros, encontrei vários lugares citando esse erro, porém nada funciona, já estou há uma semana tentando corrigi-lo:

```
C:\Users\DEV005\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\52848053fe321f69e8475a1f12a2682e\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml
Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\DEV005\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\52848053fe321f69e8475a1f12a2682e\res\values\values.xml
Error:(1452, 5) error: resource android:color/button_material_light is private.
Error:(252, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(252, 5) error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
D:\GitHub\KwikView-master\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml
Error:(11) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Error:(7) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Error:(11) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
D:\GitHub\KwikView-master\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(1881) resource android:color/button_material_light is private.
Error:(298) resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(298) resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
Error:failed linking references.
```

Esse projeto inicialmente foi desenvolvido no eclipse fiz a migração dele para o android-studio, mas acredito que ainda esta faltando alguma coisa.

**Extra**

Ainda tenho 3 bibliotecas e dentro de uma delas também da esse erro, por isso acho que é algo de configuração:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.1'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
}
```

Comment: Já tentou dar um clean no projeto pelo Android Studio?

Comment: Já sim, já fui direto apagar os arquivos também.